# How to make communication between two docker containers running on two different hosts?

Tags: networking, docker, containers

I explored basics of docker. While exploring networking part, I found docker0 bridge which allows communication between two containers running on same host. But, I have two containers running on two different hosts. Does anyone know how to make communication between these two containers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are couple of solutions:

- You can use docker "Overlay networking" which provides a limited functionalities at this time. (https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-overlay/)
- You can use docker network plugins like: weave (https://github.com/weaveworks/weave), calico (http://www.projectcalico.org/) and others.
- You can use totally different approach such a Kubernetes (http://kubernetes.io/) container orchestration tool which provides built-in routing mechanism as well.

There are even more options but not that popular.

Comment: @ Boynux Thanks for reply. I tried networking using overlay driver for that I found video on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mfGKadj1BwE )